# extract integer from txt file java

Tags: java

I have a big problem with extracting some integer values from a file which looks like:

> [41;  48;  36;  128;  1;...........105]

I was trying to do it by this code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("ala1.txt"));
        int [] tall = new int [800];
        int i = 0;

        while(scanner.hasNext())
             {
             if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
                tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
             }
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me ??

Comment: `it doesn't work`, be more specific.

Comment: How does it not work?  Are you getting an error somewhere?  Are you getting unexpected output?

Comment: I expect your problem has to do with the fact that `[41;`, `48;` and so on are not integers.

Comment: well, you have to skip the `[` and `;`, currently you are expecting integer after integer

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that Scanner sees characters like `[`, `:` as proper text, so it can't parse token like `[41;` or `48;` as integer. To solve this problem you could set Scanner to treat every non-digit character as delimiter.

Since Scanner uses regex syntax you could use delimiter like `\D+` which represents

- `+` one or more
- `\D` non-digit character

So your code can look something like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("ala1.txt"));
scanner.useDelimiter("\\D+");

while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all the integers from the line:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("ala1.txt"));
String line = scanner.nextLine();
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(line);
while(m.find()) {
    ints.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import Java.io.FileReader; 

public class ReadLine
{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("youtFile.txt"));
  try
  {
    String line;
    while((line= br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.pringln(line)
        int vl=Integer.parseInt(line);
    }
  }
 catch(Esception exo)
 {

 }

 finally
 {
    br.close();
  }

}
```

If More than one value in one line so you can use method of split. than parse in to integer.

import java.io.BufferedReader; 
    import Java.io.FileReader;

```
public class ReadLine
{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("youtFile.txt"));
  try
  {
    String line;
    while((line= br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.pringln(line)
       for(int i=0i<line.split(",").length)
       {
            int vl=Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[i]);
       } 
    }
  }
 catch(Esception exo)
 {

 }

 finally
 {
    br.close();
  }

}
```